# Convolution tends to zero

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

$f, g ∈L^1$, and $g$ is bounded. $f \ast g$ is the convolution, i.e.
 $f\ast g(x)=\int_{R}{f(x-y)\ g(y)dy}$.

Prove that $f \ast g→0$, when $|x|→+∞$.

This is an exercise from the Real Analysis of Stein.

I've proved that the convolution is uniformly continuous, but I don't know what to do next.

I also try to imitate the proof of the Riemann-Lebsgue Theorem, but fail, as the function is no longer periodic.

Any hint will be appreciated!!

Comment: Do you know that $C_c(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $L^1(\mathbb R)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use what's said in the comment part. You can find a series of continuous functions with compact support that approximate the f in $L^1\ $ norm. And the situation when f is a continuous functions with compact support is trivial.

Comment: Good, thanks a lot!!  That's what I've tried. Now I could solve it.